# UIBezierPath *not* showing?

Tags: uibezierpath

I am developing a game in which my Locomotive is following a `UIBezierPath` that mimics an oval shaped Track.

The math of the following is **not** "adding up" .. if it is, I am obviously not understanding the math of the layout.

Bottom line = the following code does **not** display the `UIBezierPath`.

Here's the code that creates this `UIBezierPath` .. please note the math in the comments:

```
func createTrainPath() {
        
    trackRect = CGRect(x: 0.0,
                       y: 0.0 - roomHeight/2 + tracksHeight,
                       width: tracksWidth,
                       height: tracksHeight)
    // trackRect = (0.0, -207.0, 940.0, 476.0)   // portrait
    // trackRect = (0.0, -274.0, 470.0, 238.0)   // landscape
    print("trackRect = \(trackRect!)")
    trackPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: trackRect)

    let theTrackShapeNode = SKShapeNode(path: trackPath.cgPath, centered: true)
    theTrackShapeNode.zPosition = 100   // for testing
    theTrackShapeNode.position = myTracks.position
    theTrackShapeNode.lineWidth = 4.0
    theTrackShapeNode.strokeColor = SKColor.blue

    if let ourScene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
        print("here")   // this shows
        ourScene.addChild(theTrackShapeNode)   // does *not* show?
    }
        
}   // createTrainPath
```

In Portrait mode, the `UIScreen` measures 1024 x 1366 and the Track measures 1024 x 476 with its top edge down 207 from the center of the `UIScreen`.

In Landscape mode, the `UIScreen` measures 1366 x 1024 and the Track measures 1366 x 238 with its top edge down 274 from the center of the `UIScreen`.

In both modes, the bottom edge of the Track is supposed to be flush with the bottom edge of the `UIScreen` .. **and it is**.

**If** the math is correct, **then** I am obviously not understanding the math of the layout .. **because** the `UIBezierPath` is **not** showing.

The math appears correct .. but the `UIBezierPath` just is **not showing**.

So where is my brain off-center?

Answer (score 0):

The following looks suspiciously like the answer .. but I definitely don't understand why it is happening:

The suspicious line is:

```
if let ourScene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
    print("here")   // this shows
    ourScene.addChild(theTrackShapeNode)   // does *not* show?
}
```

It is totally clear to me that I am in a total fog ...

I set up my `GameScene.sks` within Xcode, which I set as `1366 x 1366`

The `frame:` designation below is in line with the `anchor` setting .. so the **fog** continues as to why the blue UIBezierPath is **not** showing

```
//  print("ourScene = \(ourScene)")
//  ourScene = <SKScene> name:'GameScene'
//                       frame:{{-683, -683}, {1366, 1366}}
//                       anchor:{0.5, 0.5}
```

Comment: In my OP, I call `trackPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: trackRect)` instead of adding lines and curves to create a `UIBezierPath` from scratch. **Is this a problem?**

Comment: I am obviously doing something extremely dumb.

Comment: Some Good News ... have been fighting another problem off and on for 2 months. Dropped it totally for 3 weeks .. returned .. found it within 5 minutes. DARN